# R loop for calculating MLE is so slow

Tags: r, performance, loops, mle

I am trying to run the following loop for calculating MLE as

```
l = matrix(0, tj, n)
```

For `n` or `tj` greater than 1000 this loop will be supper slow, is there anyway to improve this code in a more efficient way?

Thanks,

```
for (t in 1:tj) {
  for (k in 1:n) {
    if(S[t]==1) {
      for(c in 1:C) {
        l[t,k]=l[t,k]+(dt*(exp(alpha[c])*exp(-(X[k]-mx[c])^2/2/sx[c]^2))*mvnpdf(x=matrix(m[t,]),mean=mu[[c]],varcovM=sig[[c]], Log = FALSE))*exp(-LAN2[k]*dt)  
      }
    } else { 
      l[t,k]=exp(-LAN2[k]*dt)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You need to add enough code to this so that it is reproducible- what is `Spikes`?

Comment: R is a vectorized language, so you should exploit the vectorized operations in order to make it fast.

Comment: what do you mean vectorized here?

Comment: What is vectorization in R and why to use it: https://www.noamross.net/archives/2014-04-16-vectorization-in-r-why/

Comment: Vectorize and precompute (especially the exponentials).

Comment: you mean precompute()?